# Express post request flood

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request, apprequests

## Introduction

I´ve a nodejs application with express that have some post and get request. The whole website works just fine without problems.

## Problem

If I call the post request to much in time the site will crash. It will not respond to other requests. Doesn´t matter if it´s get or post request.

## My Code

### Client side

It´s a easy post request to set a client permission. There is no callback defined.

```
$.post(
   '/clients/set/client/permission',
   {
      permName: globPermissionTable[permName],
      value: checked,
      id: '<%= data[0].id %>'
   }
);
```

---

### Server side

Just a easy post segment. Even if I will uncomment all in the request it will be not response.

```
app.post('/clients/set/client/permission', function(req, res) {
   // Permissioncheck
   /*var permName = req.body.permName, val = req.body.value, id = req.body.id;
   if(helper.checkParams([permName, val, id])) {
         database.SetClientPermissions(parseInt(id), permName, (val === 'true') ? true : false);
   };*/
});
```

Comment: ummm because you're not sending a response? and not using non blocking code?

Comment: I don´t get a respone from the whole app. If I start a other request where I need a response. I don´t get it. It looks like I am banned or something like this.

Comment: No what @AyushGupta was saying it that your server code doesn't send any response. Every request needs a response even if it's empty.